# Angular CLI 1.2.6 Stopping at 14% on ng build -prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-build

I am at my wits end here and not sure what to do next.

Here is the only output I get when I run ng build --prod

`14% building modules 40/40 modules 0 active`

I have tried adding the verbose flag but it makes no difference

I have tried starting a new project and using the same set of package.json dependencies and seeing if I can run it with `ng build -prod`, Which I can. Below I have included my package.json dependencies.

Once I bring my files into the new project I get the same issue, is there something I am missing or is there a way to get more debugging information out?

Here are my package.json dependencies

`"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.3",
    "ack-angular-webcam": "1.3.12",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.31.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
    "angular2-modal": "3.0.1",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "2.6.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "arrive": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.12.4",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "domready": "1.0.8",
    "googleapis": "20.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "image-capture": "^0.3.5",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "3.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "2.19.2",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "4.3.1",
    "ng2-image-compress": "^1.0.17",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.6.1",
    "ng2-password-strength-bar": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "1.1.1",
    "nouislider": "10.1.0",
    "quagga": "0.12.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "save": "2.3.1",
    "sweetalert2": "6.6.6",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "validate": "3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.36",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.10",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.17",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try restarting your computer and building without your IDE open.

Comment: Set AOT flag false and see if it works `ng build --prod -aot=false`

Comment: The CLI is up to version 1.7.3 now. Perhaps you should consider updating to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I found the issues after some more digging and trying multiple compiler versions. It ended up being two fold, there was a circular dependency error that took some time to find. The second problem was in a component we had an OnInit function which just has this as the return -  `return;`. Once I remove these two errors, code built again. I have not yet to replicate this error.

Answer (score 1):

use command `ng build --env prod`